# Wordpress category_list issue it redirect to the no-category page what is the issue

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, wp-list-categories

when i click the list of category(sidebar) like 2021, 2022, one category link is not redirect correctly ...it goes to no-category page like this this websitname/category/no-category

Anyone try to give idea or suggestion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.